# Всплывающее окно на кнопку

Tags: html

столкнулся с такой трудностью, не получается сделать всплывающее окно на кнопку "Отправить заявку". Сейчас это так работает, человека заполняет поля на форме, нажимает отправить заявку, данные заносятся в Бд, форма обновляется. Нужно чтобы было так же, но при нажатии на кнопку Отправить заявку, было сообщение о том, что заявка успешно отправлена.

Код формы:

```
<section id="section0" class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="headerInner">
            <h2>Здравствуйте, рады видеть вас, на нашем сайте Каршеринга</h2>
            <div class="red">
            <p><b class="red"> Каршеринг — это краткосрочный прокат транспортных средств, оплата за который, как правило, начисляется поминутно. Это очень удобный способ передвижения, особенно если водитель не имеет собственного автомобиля и не любит пользоваться услугами такси.</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-30">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <form action="addmessage.php" method="POST">
                    <p>Ваше имя</p>
                    <input type="text" name="name" style="display: block"required>
                    <p>Ваш E-mail</p>
                    <input type="email" name="email" style="display: block"required>
                    <p>Ваш номер телефона</p>
                    <input type="text" name="telefon" style="display: block"placeholder="+X (XXX) XXX-XX-XX" required pattern="\+7\s?[\(]{0,1}9[0-9]{2}[\)]{0,1}\s?\d{3}[-]{0,1}\d{2}[-]{0,1}\d{2}">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-head mt-20 mb-50" value="Отправить Заявку">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: отправляете запрос на сервер через ajax. Сервер возвращает вам ответ Ok или НеОк

Comment: Можно чуть подробней

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?text=ajax&l10n=ru https://yandex.ru/search/?text=fetch https://yandex.ru/search/?text=axios